# Attempt to get a php prepare to work with two different tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, prepared-statement

I am attempting to do my first query where I send to two different db tables. I am trying to update the 'group' in the users and user_request table. I am getting an id from an AJAX call, I am using that id to find the record I am trying to update.

In the users table the id will need to find the id field.
In the user_requests table the id will need to associate with the user_id.

This is the line I am trying to change to make this send to two different db tables..

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE users,user_reuqests SET `group`=? WHERE id, user_id=?");
```

I'm getting an error responce saying the error is by the user_id part.

```
$approved_id = $_POST['id'];
$change_group = $_POST['update_group'];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE users,user_reuqests SET `group`=? WHERE id, user_id=?");
    if ( !$stmt || $con->error ) {
     // Check Errors for prepare
        die('User Group update prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt->bind_param('ii', $change_group, $approved_id)) {
    // Check errors for binding parameters
        die('User Group update bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt->execute()) {
        die('User Group update execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
```

What am I doing wrong to not get this to work and conjoin?

UPDATE: After I changed the prepare part of this, I'm now getting errors in my bind_param part of my prepared statement. How can I change this?

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE users,user_requests SET users.group=?, user_requests.group=? WHERE users.id=? AND user_requests.user_id=?");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, The WHERE clause in your query doesn't specify an id for the first constraint.

Second, `group` is ambiguous and will cause errors when you try to update it.

Your query should read:`UPDATE users,user_reuqests SET users.group=?, user_request.group=? WHERE users.id=? AND user_request.user_id=?`

Now, since we've updated the query with more place holders, we need to bind these additional placeholders to PHP variables. The new query uses both `$change_group` and `$approved_id` twice - so we need to bind each of them twice.

```
if(!$stmt->bind_param('iiii', $change_group, $change_group, $approved_id, $approved_id)) {
    // Check errors for binding parameters
        die('User Group update bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
```

When all is said and done, the final code should look like this:

```
$approved_id = $_POST['id'];
$change_group = $_POST['update_group'];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE users,user_reuqests SET users.group=?, user_request.group=? WHERE users.id=? AND user_request.user_id=?");
    if ( !$stmt || $con->error ) {
     // Check Errors for prepare
        die('User Group update prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt->bind_param('iiii', $change_group, $change_group, $approved_id, $approved_id)) {
    // Check errors for binding parameters
        die('User Group update bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt->execute()) {
        die('User Group update execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
```

More info on binding parameters to a mysqli_stmt here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Still getting a syntax error from this. `$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE users,user_reuqests SET users.group=?, user_requests.group=? WHERE users.id=?, user_requests.user_id=?");`

Comment: Oops! Sorry, the comma in the where clause should be replaced with `AND`.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: It is now saying my bind_param failed.

Comment: Yep. The query uses more placeholders (the ?'s in the query). It looks like you are bound 2 placeholders in your question - since the query I propose uses 4 placeholders, you just need to add more using the same PHP variables. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your syntax:

```
WHERE id, user_id=?
```

It should be something like this:

```
WHERE id = ? AND user_id = ?
```

Comment: I've updated my question. I am now able to get past the prepare part, but am stuck on the bind param part.